# Using a max-width container in grid-item

Tags: css, grid, containers, centering

I have a container with a max-width: 80 rem and margin-inline: auto , when I apply it on the grid, it works perfectly by centering the grid for me from 80 rem

```
 <div class="grid-container container">
        <header class="primary-header flex "> //i want to put container class here
            <h1 class="logo uppercase text-white">adventure</h1>
            <button class="mobile-nav-toggle" aria-controls="primary-navigation" aria- 
            expanded="false"><span class="sr-only">Menu</span></button>
            <nav class="flex">
                <ul id="primary-navigation" class="primary-navigation flex text-white capitalise 
                letter-spacing-3 fs-base" data-visible="false">
                    <li><a href="">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">tours</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">explore</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">about</a></li>
                    <li><button class="btn bg-pink text-white ">contact</button></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main></main>
    </div>
```

but I would like to put the container class in the item header cell, but it does not work correctly, it centers all the header content without having reached the size of 80rem, and i dont understand why? i know ils because margin-inline but normally it centered at 80rem not before.

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: var(--gap, 2rem);
}
.grid-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  max-width: 80rem; 
  margin-inline: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<div class="grid-container container">`
[image: grid-container]

When 'container' class is applied to the parent 'grid-container' `div`, it has `max-width: 80rem;` and `margin-inline: auto;`. Therefore, when the viewport width is greater than 80rem, the available inline margin is split and applied equally on both sides between `div` and its parent (`body`), which centers `div`. `header` is a child of `div`, so it has the default left alignment inside its container.

`<header class="primary-header flex container">`
[image: header]
When 'container' class is applied to `header`, the width of `div` is not restrained and `header` now has all the available inline margin divided and applied between itself and `div`, causing `header` to be centered. The available margin is from the *actual* width of `header` (almost 40rem) and not from the max-width declaration.

If you want only `header` to have a max-width and not `main`, you can achieve your desired result by adding `width: 100%` to `.container`

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: var(--gap, 2rem);
}
.grid-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 80rem; 
  margin-inline: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <header class="primary-header flex container">
    <h1 class="logo uppercase text-white">adventure</h1>
    <button class="mobile-nav-toggle" aria-controls="primary-navigation" aria-expanded="false"><span class="sr-only">Menu</span></button>
    <nav class="flex">
      <ul id="primary-navigation" class="primary-navigation flex text-white capitalise letter-spacing-3 fs-base" data-visible="false">
        <li><a href="">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">tours</a></li>
        <li><a href="">explore</a></li>
        <li><a href="">about</a></li>
        <li><button class="btn bg-pink text-white ">contact</button></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main></main>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont understand why "header now has all the available inline margin divided and applied between itself and div", normally header has a width of 100% of its parent

Comment: @MiaWD Yes, but because `width` is not defined, `header` is only as wide as its contents. Combined with auto margins, the difference in width between the contents and 100% of the parent container is divided on each side, centering `header` inside of its parent container.