Max-width doesnt work on grid item container
I have a main tag as a container with the display of grid, justify/align-items are set to center, inside it there's a div container.
I'm trying to specify a max-width of 370px but it won't work unless I remove the align and justify properties. I saw a similar post where there's a flex container, the problem was fixed by setting the width of 100% and the max-width together. This solved my problem at first but when I scale down the width of with the dev tools the div container won't shrink. In short, is there any way to apply a max-width for an item inside a grid container? Below is the code excerpt


body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--Off-Black);
    font-family: var(--inter-regular);
    text-align: center;
}
main{
    min-height: inherit;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.sn-container, .attr-container{
    outline: auto;
    background-color: var(--Grey);
    color: var(--White);
}
.sn-container{
    grid-area: 1/1/3/2;
    margin: 2em;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px; /*max-width is being ignored. if i set width: 100% 600px wont be ignored but the max-width responsiveness wont work when i scale down the viewport */
}
.attr-container{
    grid-area: 1/1/2/2;
}
 <main>
    <div class="attr-container">
      <p>Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a></p>
      <p>Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="sn-container">
      <img src="./assets/images/avatar-jessica.jpeg" title="Jessica Randall" alt="Jessica Randall's picture">
      <h1>Jessica Randall</h1>
      <address>London, United Kingdom</address>
      <q>Front-end developer and avid reader.</q>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button>GitHub</button>
        <button>Frontend Mentor</button>
        <button>LinkedIn</button>
        <button>Twitter</button>
        <button>Instagram</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>




Hello:) I think these can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76510104/using-a-max-width-container-in-grid-item and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025403/max-width-with-css-grid
